# Buffered and pageSize issue in store with combobox. (With ExtJs 4.2.0 version)

Tags: extjs

I am just migrating from ExtJs 4.1.0 to ExtJs 4.2.0 and I faced the following issue

In our application we have made a custom picker using Combobox. In which we have added the Grid in the picker. This picker works fine in ExtJs 4.1.0 but it behaves very wierdly when I replace the library i.e, ExtJs 4.2.0.

Actually we are using the buffered: true in the Combobox store( Custom Picker in our case ).
    Which is creating the problem in ExtJs 4.2.0.

Please look into this fiddle which is demonstrating my problem:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SkTvE/1/)

> Ext.onReady(function () {
>       Ext.define("Post", {
>           extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
>           fields: [
>               {name: 'id', mapping: 'post_id'},
>               {name: 'title', mapping: 'topic_title'},
>               {name: 'topicId', mapping: 'topic_id'},
>               {name: 'author', mapping: 'author'},
>               {name: 'lastPost', mapping: 'post_time', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
>               {name: 'excerpt', mapping: 'post_text'}
>           ]
>       });
>
> ```
> ds = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
>     pageSize: 10,
>     model: 'Post',
>     //buffered: true,
>     leadingBufferZone: 10,
>     proxy: {
>         type: 'jsonp',
>         url : 'http://www.sencha.com/forum/topics-remote.php',
>         reader: {
>             type: 'json',
>             root: 'topics',
>             totalProperty: 'totalCount'
>         }
>     }
> });
>
> panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
>     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
>     title: 'Search the Ext Forums',
>     width: 600,
>     bodyPadding: 10,
>     layout: 'anchor',
>
>     items: [{
>         xtype: 'combo',
>         store: ds,
>         displayField: 'title',
>         typeAhead: false,
>         hideLabel: true,
>         hideTrigger:false,
>         anchor: '100%',
>         pageSize: 10,
>         listConfig: {
>             loadingText: 'Searching...',
>             emptyText: 'No matching posts found.',
>
>             // Custom rendering template for each item
>             getInnerTpl: function() {
>                 return '<a class="search-item" href="http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?t={topicId}&p={id}">'
> ```
>
> +
>                           '
>
> #### {[Ext.Date.format(values.lastPost, "M j, Y")]}
> by {author}{title}
>
> ' +
>                           '{excerpt}' +
>                       '';
>                   }
>               }
>           }, {
>               xtype: 'component',
>               style: 'margin-top:10px',
>               html: 'Live search requires a minimum of 4 characters.'
>           }]
>       });    });

This fiddle works fine while I have commented buffered: true.

But when you will:

1. Uncomment buffered:true from the store.
2. And comment pageSize where combobox is creating (not in store).

   Then you will find that there will be no result fetch (with ExtJs 4.2.0).
   And the same scenerio is working fine in the ExtJs 4.1.0.

   If it is working with ExtJs 4.1.0 then why not with ExtJs 4.2.0. Is this the ExtJs
   4.2.0.
   Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The combobox does not support a buffered store as far as I know.  You would need to actually render a grid in the combo and use a buffered store for the grid...the combo itself would not have a store.

See this post http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?248251

Here is a plugin that may help do what you want http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?140667-Put-A-Grid-In-ComboBox-%E2%80%94%E2%80%94-Magic-GridCombo